# How to filter file selection

Tags: perl

I have files of the form

```
wrfout_d01_2024-02-08_01_00_00
wrfout_d01_2024-02-08_02_00_00
wrfout_d01_2024-02-08_03_00_00
...
```

where the last nonzero digit is the day of the month. I want to select only files from 1st to 10th or from 11th to 20th. With my code below for selecting 11 to 20, it is taking 1 -20.

```
while (my $file=readdir $DIR){
 next if -d $file;
 if($file =~ /^wrfout_$Dom[$kk]/){
  foreach(my $ii = 11; $ii <= 20; ++$ii){
   next unless($file =~ /^wrfout_$Dom[$kk]_\d{4}-\d{2}-$ii/);
   copy("$INPUT_DIR[$kk]/$file","$DATA_DIR") or die "Copy failed: $!";
  }
 }
}
```

All the variables @INPUT_DIR, $DATA_DIR, $DIR are defined elsewhere.
How do I modify my code to make the correct selection?

Comment: You can have just `$DATA_DIR`, no need for `"$DATA_DIR"`.

Comment: Ideally you'd have a function here that given a filename returns the day, and then you can test that in isolation. This is a bit cluttered even by Perl standards.

Comment: What is the variable `$kk`?

Comment: Also consider something simple like split on `[\-_]` and access the filename like an array. This tends to be more reliable than code like `substr()`.

Comment: The code is very long, there are several INPUT_DIRs where files are copied from to one $DATA_DIR. There is a loop for $INPUT_DIR[$kk]. I will try to sort the files in order, put them in an array and select the range I want from the array. Thank you very much for the ideas.

Comment: When you say "**last** non-zero digit", you mean "next to last", correct? The `08` and not the `01`, `02`, `03`? Your code seems to imply the latter.

Comment: What I was trying to mean is the day of the month. The digits are YYYY-mm-dd_00_00_00. I was taking dd as the last nonzero digits.

Answer (score 2):

`for($iday >= 11 && $iday <= 20)` should be `if($iday >= 11 && $iday <= 20)`.

You could also do the validation of the filename *and* extraction of the day at the same time:

Example:

```perl
while (my $file = readdir $DIR) {
    next if -d $file;
    # validate the beginning of the filename and extract the day in one go:
    if ($file =~ /^wrfout_$Dom[$kk]_\d{4}-\d{2}-(\d{2})/) {
#                                               ^     ^
#                                               capture

        $iday = $1;                         # captured in the above match

        if ($iday >= 11 && $iday <= 20) {   # if instead of for
#       if ( 11 <= $iday <= 20 ) {          # modern syntax for the same thing
            copy("$INPUT_DIR[$kk]/$file", $DATA_DIR) or die "Copy failed: $!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In newer Perls can also do `if ( 11 <= $iday <= 20 )`

Comment: @zdim Wow, cool! I'll edit, thanks!

Comment: `perl -wE'$n = shift//5;  if (4 <= $n <= 8) { say $n }'`

Comment: @zdim My brain just broke :-)

Comment: "_brain just broke_" -- you mean it's that cool? :)

Comment: @zdim It may be, but my internal parser just went offline so I'm not qualified to judge :-)

Comment: Time for some chillin' !

Comment: @zdim In newer Perls? From which Perl version can you do this trick?

Comment: @Bork I have v5.38.2 where it works but I'm not sure when it was introduced.

Comment: @Bork Apparently it's since [v5.32 (delta)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5320delta#Chained-comparisons-capability)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the files that fit a certain format, using a [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) might be preferable. That way you only loop over the files that you are interested in, and not all the files in the directory. `readdir` also finds hidden files, e.g. `.`, or `.htaccess`, which is not what you want in this case.

Also, as Ted says, you need to change `for` to `if`. Otherwise you get a loop of one iteration, with the value of the comparison stored in `$_`.

Here is a mockup file of the logic:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $file (glob "wrfout_$Dom[$kk]*") {  # get a list of files
    chomp($file);
    next if -d $file;
    # below line checks format, and captures and declares $iday
    if (my ($iday) = $file =~ /^wrfout_$Dom[$kk]_\d{4}-\d{2}-(\d{2})/) {
        if ($iday >= 11 && $iday <= 20) {
            # you do not need a full path to $file, if its in the current dir
            copy($file, $DATA_DIR) or die "Copy failed: $!";
            # die could be the wrong response for large batches of files
        }
    }
}
```